# Mysql : 'UNIQUE' constraint over a large string

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema, rdbms

What could be the possible downside of having **UNIQUE** constraint **for a large string** (varchar) (roughly ***100 characters*** or so) in MYSQL during :

> - insert phase
> - retrieval phase (on another primary key)

Can the length of the query impact the performance of read/writes ? (Apart from disk/memory usage for book-keeping).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Several issues.  There is a limit on the size of a column in an index (191, 255, 767, 3072, etc, depending on various things).

**Your column fits within the limit.**

Simply make a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY` key for that column.  There are minor performance concerns, but keep this in mind:  *Fetching* a row is more costly than any datatype issues involving the key used to locate it.

**Your column won't fit.**

Now the workarounds get ugly.

- Index prefixing (`INDEX foo(50)`) has a number of problems and inefficiencies.
- `UNIQUE foo(50)` is flat out wrong.  It is declaring that the first 50 characters are constrained to be unique, *not* the entire column.
- Workarounds with hashing the string (cf md5, sha1, etc) have a number of problems and inefficiencies.  Still, this may be the only viable way to enforce uniqueness of a long string.

(I'll elaborate if needed.)

**Fetching a row**  (Assuming the statement is parsed and the `PRIMARY KEY` is available.)

1. Drill down the BTree containing the data (and ordered by the PK).  This may involve bring a block (or more) from disk into the buffer_pool.
2. Parse the block to find the row.  (There are probably dozens of rows in the block.)
3. At some point in the process lock the row for reading and/or be blocked by some other connection that is, say, updating or deleting.
4. Pick apart the row -- that is, split into columns.
5. For any text/blob columns needed, reach into the off-record storage.  (Wide columns are not stored with the narrow columns of the row; they are stored in other block(s).)  The costly part is locating (and reading from disk if not cached) the extra block(s) containing the big `TEXT`/`BLOB`.
6. Convert from the internal storage (not word-aligned, little-endian, etc) into the desired format.  (A small amount of CPU code, but necessary.  This means that the data files are compatible across OS and even hardware.)

If the next step is to compare two strings (for JOIN or ORDER BY), then that a simple subroutine call to a scan over however many characters there are.  (OK, most utf8 collations are not 'simple'.)  And, yes, comparing two INTs would be faster.

**Disk space**

Should `INT` be used instead of `VARCHAR(100)` for the `PRIMARY KEY`?  It depends.

- Every secondary key has a copy of the `PRIMARY KEY` in it.  This implies that a PK that is `VARCHAR(100)` makes secondary indexes bulkier than if the PK were `INT`.
- If there are no secondary keys, then the above comment implies that `INT` is the bulkier approach!
- If there are more than 2 secondary keys, then using varchar is likely to be bulkier.
- (For exactly one secondary key, it is a tossup.)

**Speed**

- If all the columns of a `SELECT` are in a secondary index, the query may be performed entirely in the index's BTree.  ("Covering index", as indicated in `EXPLAIN` by "Using index".)  This is sometimes a worthwhile optimization.
- If the above does not apply, and it is useful to look up row(s) via a secondary index, then there are *two* BTree lookups -- once in the index, then via the PK.  This is sometimes a noticeable slowdown.
- The point here is that artificially adding an `INT id` *may* be slower than simply using the bulky `VARCHAR` as the PK.  *Each case should be judged on its tradeoffs; I am not making a blanket statement.*

Comment: Can you please elaborate 'Fetching a row is more costly than any datatype issues involving the key used to locate it.'

Comment: @RickJames, can you explain a bit about this `For any text/blob columns needed, reach into the off-record storage` and `Convert from the internal storage into desired format`

Comment: @Harshit - When trying to decrease the elapsed time taken by a particular query, the number of rows touched is the dominant factor in the time.  2nd would be caching, sorting, etc.  The complexity of expressions comes in 3rd.

Comment: @Harshit - (continued) To add an index entry, the block where that key will go must be fetched, checked for dup (if it is declared UNIQUE), a new entry made, and finally write the block back to disk.  Handling a 40-byte varchar is not a much bigger percentage of the total than a 4-byte INT.

Comment: @swayamraina - I added to item 5 to further explain off-record storage.  The "word-alignment" and "big/little-endian" are hardware terms relating primarily to how a 32-bit `INT` is stored into 4 bytes.  (Very low-level stuff -- SQL programmers don't have to know about, but I am trying to be 'complete' in discussing the issues.)  I don't think there is any hardware these days that is not 2's complement for ints and IEEE-754-compliant for `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` or EBCDIC chars.  If so, those would be other issues.  See Wikipedia.

Comment: I added semi-relevant discussions on disk space and speed.